# Inputting structure members into printf function and too many arguments error

Tags: c, printf, structure

Hi can anybody tell me the issue of what's going on in the **printf** function? I keep getting an error of

> warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]  time2.hour, time2.min, time2.sec,
>   time3.hour, time3.min, time3.sec);

and then

> warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Anybody give some pointers as to how to fix? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time
{
    int hour;
    int min;
    int sec;
};

int main (void)
{
    struct time time1, time2, time3;
    struct time elapsed_time (struct time time1, struct time time2);

    printf("Enter your first time (hh:mm:ss) : ");
    scanf ("%i:%i:%i", &time1.hour, &time1.min, &time1.sec);

    printf("Enter your second time (hh:mm:ss) : ");
    scanf ("%i:%i:%i", &time2.hour, &time2.min, &time2.sec);

    time3 = elapsed_time(time1,time2);

    printf("The time difference between %.2i:%.2i:%.2i & %.2i:%.2i:%.2i",
            "is %.2i:%.2i:%.2i.\n", time1.hour, time1.min, time1.sec,
            time2.hour, time2.min, time2.sec, time3.hour, time3.min, time3.sec);

    return 0;
}

struct time elapsed_time (struct time time1, struct time time2)
{
    struct time time3 = { 0, 0, 0 };

    time3.hour = time2.hour - time1.hour;
    time3.min = time2.min - time1.min;
    time3.sec = time2.sec - time1.sec;

    return time3;
}
```

Comment: If you want two string literals to be concatenated, don't put a `,` between them.

Comment: I think you already have too much **pointers**. No need to give some more ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two string literals in your long printf statement, but the printf statement only allows one string at the beginning, and it must be the one that contains all the %.2i format placeholders.

Right now, printf gets the first one, and then tries to use the second string as an input argument to the first.

Join those two strings into 1 string, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, how can i concatenate multi-line printf statements into one?

Comment: Either just remove the "," and make it one long line, or build it up into one string by concatenating the pieces. Like part1="part 1 text"; part2 = "part 2 text", etc, then strcat them together. Look up "how to concatenate strings in C" on the forum here, and you'll see examples.